# Blankline after foreach loops

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have this foreach loop:

```
echo '';                
foreach ($r['result']['achievements']['0']['achievements'] as $item) {
echo '
<div class="achiev-title">   ', $item['title'], '</div>
<div class="description">      ', $item['description'], '</div>

 <div class="criteria">'; 
 if(!empty($item['criteria'])){       
             foreach ($item['criteria'] as $item2){
             echo '<li>
           ', $item2['description'], ' </li>';
            }

        }

}
echo '
</div>
<br/>';
?>
```

I want to have a blankline everytime the two loops are finished. For that i´ve tried the `<br/>` but without any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```
  echo '<div>';                
           foreach ($r['result']['achievements']['0']['achievements'] as $item) 
           {
              echo '<div class="achiev-title">'.$item['title'].'</div>
             <div class="description">'.$item['description'].'</div>

             <div class="criteria">'; 
               if(!empty($item['criteria'])) 
               {       
                  foreach ($item['criteria'] as $item2)
                  {
                    echo '<li>'.$item2['description'].'</li>';
                  }
               }
       echo '</div></br>';

         }
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this

```
<?php
    $r['result']['achievements']['0']['achievements'] = array();
    $item['criteria'] = array();
    foreach ($r['result']['achievements']['0']['achievements'] as $item) {
        echo '<div class="achiev-title">   '. $item['title']. '</div>
        <div class="description">      '. $item['description']. '</div>
        <div class="criteria">'; 
        if(!empty($item['criteria'])){       
            foreach ($item['criteria'] as $item2){
             echo '<li>'. $item2['description']. ' </li>';
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</div><br/>';
?>
```

Remove line 2 and 3 for your code xD

Comment: Hm strange, doesn´t have any effects on the html output.

Comment: I have tested it. Had output with <br/>. Review your code plz

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have ended your div and placed your br within the item loop. If you want to print a br after the two loops are finished, then you should print it at the end of the first loop($item loop) brace.

Also, you should try and write cleaner code by separating your HTML and PHP in separate tags instead of echoing out HTML within the PHP itself.

Try this:

```
<?php foreach ($r['result']['achievements']['0']['achievements'] as $item) {    ?>
 <div class="achiev-title"><?php echo ', $item['title'], '; ?></div>
 <div class="description"><?php echo ', $item['description'], '; ?></div>
 <div class="criteria">
   <?php if(!empty($item['criteria'])) {       
     foreach ($item['criteria'] as $item2) {
   ?>
       <li><?php echo ', $item2['description'], '; ?></li>
     <?php } // $item2 loop ends ?>
   <?php } // if ends ?>
  </div>
<?php } // $item loop ends ?>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it seemed you were using commas(**,**) were you were supposed to use dots (**.**) and then single quotes and double quotes here and there. Anyways, you could try a much concise approach that. Here you go:

```
<?php
    foreach ($r['result']['achievements']['0']['achievements'] as $item) { ?>
        <div class="achiev-title"><?php echo $item['title'];       ?></div>
        <div class="description"><?php  echo $item['description']  ?></div>
        <div class="criteria">
            <?php           
                if(!empty($item['criteria'])){
                    foreach ($item['criteria'] as $item2){
                        echo "<li>{$item2['description']}</li>";
                    }       
                }       
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```